# XQuery to remove all elements with attribute onlyChannels="print" from XML file

Tags: xml, xquery, xquery-3.0, xquery-3.1

Trying to remove all elements with attribute `onlyChannels="print"` from XML Using XQuery
the element with `onlyChannels="print"` can be anywhere and at different levels.

Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<abstractGroup>
   <abstract type="main" xml:lang="en">
      <title type="main">Abstract</title>
      <p>900 000 ha along the test of north</p>
      <p onlyChannels="print">Abstract</p>
   </abstract>
   <abstract onlyChannels="online" type="main" xml:lang="es">
      <title type="main">Resumen</title>
      <p>La orsdft de los trópifdaa</p>
   </abstract>
   <full type="main" xml:lang="en">
      <p onlyChannels="print">full</p>
      <p>900 000 ha along the test of north‐east</p>
      <doc>
      <p onlyChannels="print"> do not print</p>
      <p> print </p>
      </doc>
   </full>
</abstractGroup>
```

---

expcted output XML

```
<abstractGroup>
   <abstract type="main" xml:lang="en">
      <title type="main">Abstract</title>
      <p>900 000 ha along the test of north</p>
   </abstract>
   <abstract onlyChannels="online" type="main" xml:lang="es">
      <title type="main">Resumen</title>
      <p>La orsdft de los trópifdaa</p>
   </abstract>
   <full type="main" xml:lang="en">
      <p>900 000 ha along the test of north‐east</p>
     <doc>
      <p> print </p>
      </doc>
   </full>
</abstractGroup>
```

I was trying this XQuery but it's only removing elements in the first level and without XML tags.

```
let $root:=  abstractGroup/*/*[not(self::*/@onlyChannels="print")]
return $root
```

what I got :

> ```
> Abstract 
> 900 000 ha along the test of north 
> Resumen 
> La orsdft de los trópifdaa
> 900 000 ha along the test of north‐east
>
>    do not print
>    print
> ```

How I can print the xml tags and removing all elements with attribute onlyChannels="print"

Comment: Which XQuery processor is that? Does it support XQuery update? Or does it support (like Saxon 10 or 9) XSLT as well? In XSLT you could declare the identity transformation as the base template with e.g. `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` and add an empty template `<xsl:template match="*[@onlyChannels = 'print']"/>` to delete any such elements and you are done.

Comment: In XQuery Update, as supported by BaseX, for instance, all you need is `delete nodes //*[@onlyChannels = 'print']`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could run it through a [recursive typeswitch function](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery/Typeswitch_Transformations) to transform the XML:

```
declare function local:filter($nodes as node()*) as node()*
{
  for $n in $nodes return
  typeswitch ($n)
    case element () return 
      if ($n[@onlyChannels="print"]) 
      then local:filter($n/node()) 
      else element { node-name($n) } { $n/@*, local:filter($n/node())}
    default return $n
};

let $doc :=
<abstractGroup>
   <abstract type="main" xml:lang="en">
      <title type="main">Abstract</title>
      <p>900 000 ha along the test of north</p>
      <p onlyChannels="print">Abstract</p>
   </abstract>
   <abstract onlyChannels="online" type="main" xml:lang="es">
      <title type="main">Resumen</title>
      <p>La orsdft de los trópifdaa</p>
   </abstract>
   <full type="main" xml:lang="en">
      <p onlyChannels="print">full</p>
      <p>900 000 ha along the test of north‐east</p>
      <doc>
      <p onlyChannels="print"> do not print</p>
      <p> print </p>
      </doc>
   </full>
</abstractGroup>

return local:filter($doc)
```