# How to skip on specific elements?

Tags: xquery

I have this code on XQuery:

```
<title-group>
            <article-title xml:lang="en"><inline-formula id="IEq1"><alternatives>
                        <mml:math>
                            <mml:mi>Λ</mml:mi>
                        </mml:math>
                        <tex-math id="IEq1_TeX">\documentclass[12pt]{minimal}
                            \usepackage{amsmath} \usepackage{wasysym} \usepackage{amsfonts}
                            \usepackage{amssymb} \usepackage{amsbsy} \usepackage{mathrsfs}
                            \usepackage{upgreek} \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-69pt}
                            \begin{document}$\Lambda$\end{document}</tex-math>
                        <inline-graphic xlink:href="13360_2019_12756_Article_IEq1.gif"/>
                    </alternatives></inline-formula>CDM-like models with future
                singularities</article-title>
        </title-group>
```

the results that I want to show is only 'article-title' element, without 'inline-formula' element. how can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, which version of XQuery, which XQuery processor do you use? What have you tried, which result exactly do you want (show is as a code snippet as well)?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69435707/xquery-to-remove-all-elements-with-attribute-onlychannels-print-from-xml-file